# Permission access error while installing Firebase tools/CLI

Tags: macos, firebase, terminal, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to download Firebase CLI in the terminal by entering 
`npm install -g firebase-tools` and I get the error below, ( i have also tried `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` to no avail). Who can see what is going wrong?

> Bens-MBP:Grapevine2019 benpalmer$ npm install -g firebase-tools
>   npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
>   npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
>   npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
>   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' }
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/benpalmer/.npm/_logs/2018-05-26T11_52_59_346Z-debug.log
>   Bens-MBP:Grapevine2019 benpalmer$

Answer (score 1):

You could try running this command as an administrator, or check the documentations from npm about preventing permission errors.
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions